# Rolling back on query one day before SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a query in which for every weekday, it picks always the last business day, except for Mondays. On Mondays, it should always pick the last Friday.

To achieve this, it could be either done by selecting or creating an additional column that allows to identify these cases.

**Examples:**

- If first_date = Tuesday then pick Monday
- If first_date = Thursday then pick Wednesday
- If first_date = Monday then pick Friday

**Here my query:**

```
SELECT name, 
       first_date, 
       last_day, 
       product, 
       TO_DATE(first_date) - TO_DATE(last_day) AS d, 
       CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(first_date, 'D') = '7' THEN -2
            WHEN TO_CHAR(first_date, 'D') = '6' THEN -1
            ELSE 0
       END
FROM t1.mydata
WHERE d > 50
```

**Any ideas on how to do this best?**

Comment: have you taken into account red days (christmas, easter, etc..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TRUNC(first_date) - TRUNC(fisrt_date, 'IW')` to compare the date (truncated to midnight) to the start of the ISO week (which is always midnight on Monday). This will work regardless of the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` or `NLS_TERRITORY` settings.

```sql
SELECT name, 
       first_date, 
       last_day, 
       product, 
       last_day - first_date AS d,
       first_date
       - CASE TRUNC(first_date) - TRUNC(fisrt_date, 'IW')
         WHEN 0 THEN -3 -- Monday
         WHEN 6 THEN -2 -- Sunday
                ELSE -1 -- Other days
         END AS prev_business_day
FROM   t1.mydata
WHERE  last_day - first_date > 50
```

---

*Note: If you use `TO_CHAR(first_date, 'D')` then if the day is Monday then it will return: `1` in most of Europe; `2` in America; `3` in some Middle-Eastern countries; and `4` in Bangladesh as they all consider the first day of the week to be a different day [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c453d2041c4d5768d8882803ae2f8abe). This is based on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting and is not something that can be overridden in the query.*

*Note: If you use `TO_CHAR(first_date, 'Dy')` then it will use the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` session parameter to set the date language so your query would only work in one language. You would need to specify a third argument (i.e. `TO_CHAR(first_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')`) for it to work consistently in an International setting.*

Comment: thank you, this solved my issue as I was expecting

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional with `TO_CHAR` conversion along with `Dy` (or `Day`) argument rather than using those integer representations, *those might fail for some regions*, for weekdays such that

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(your_datecol,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') ='Mon' THEN 
                  'Fri'
            WHEN TO_CHAR(your_datecol,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') = 'Sun' THEN    
                  Null
            ELSE 
                 TO_CHAR(your_datecol-1,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
             END AS last_business_day          
  FROM your_table
```

ignoring the local offical vacancies.